# Why am I getting the parent and child window handlers same when I print them?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, iterator, window-handles

```
String parentWindowHandler = browser.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
System.out.println(parentWindowHandler);

browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn-danger")).click();
String subWindowHandler = null;

Set<String> handles = browser.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
}
browser.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);
System.out.println(subWindowHandler);// switch to popup window
```

Comment: Add some sleep after click `"button.btn-danger"` when debug

Comment: @Rahul, let me know clicking on this `browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn-danger")).click();` open in new window/tab or in popup? If popup..whether it is in frame?

Comment: @GauravGenius.... Thanks.  It was a pop-up.It was not a browser tab nor a browser window. I am done with this now as I did not require to store/iterate/switch the window in this case.

Comment: @Yong. It did work. Thanks.Problem was like ,While I was finding the elements on  my pop-up page loading was not done in full.I did stop my testing method thread to wait for the page load and did work.

Comment: @Rahul, Great :)

Answer (score -1):

Iterator in the top of your collection. When you to `iterator.next()` it will be your parent window only. If you want to get child window handle, do on more `iterator.next()`

```
while (iterator.hasNext()){
parentWindowHandler = iterator.next();
subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
```

}

Comment: It had use loop to iterator per handle per time, no need to iterator two handles per time.  There is no differencen.